# Redefine \newcommand to insert code at start and end of custom macros

Tags: macros, xparse, debugging

I would like to be able to insert code into the definitions of my custom macros, without having to modify *each* macro definition.   This seemed like a simple case of redefining `\newcommand`, but this turns out not to be so easy (well for me anyway). I end up with:

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \MacroB.
> to be read again
> 1 l.45 \newcommand*{\MacroB}[1]{b#1b}

My guess is that somewhere I need to double up the `#` but I don't understand why, and guessing which ones need to be doubled up did not work. So perhaps that is not the problem.

### Notes:

- The MWE below compiles fine -- one needs to uncomment the `\def\EnableTrace{}` to see the problem.
- The goal of this is to build up a stack trace of macros as they are being called.

### Code:

```
%\def\EnableTrace{}
\documentclass{article}

%% All packages included here...
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}


%% Start of custom macros...
\ifdefined\EnableTrace
    \newcounter{NestingDepth}
    \newcommand*{\StartMacro}[1]{%
        \typeout{**** DEBUG: (Depth=\arabic{NestingDepth}) Started macro "\string#1".}%
        \stepcounter{NestingDepth}%
    }%
    \newcommand*{\EndMacro}[1]{%
        \addtocounter{NestingDepth}{-1}%
        \typeout{**** DEBUG: (Depth=\arabic{NestingDepth}) Completed macro "\string#1".}%
    }%
    % --------------
    \LetLtxMacro{\OldNewcommand}{\newcommand}%
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\newcommand}{%
        s%    #1 = * (ignored for now to keep the code below simple)
        m%    #2 = macro name
        O{1}% #3 = number of paramaters
        o%    #4 = default value for first optional parameter (if there is one)
        m%    #5 = code to execute
    }{%
        %
        \ifnum#3=1\relax
            \OldNewcommand{#2}{\StartMacro{#2}#5\EndMacro{#2}}%
        \else
            \IfBooleanTF{#4}{%
                % first parameter of macro being defined is optional, as default value is provided
                \OldNewcommand{#2}[#3][#4]{\StartMacro{#2}#5\EndMacro{#2}}%
            }{%
                % first parameter of macro being defined is mandatory
                \OldNewcommand{#2}[#3]{\StartMacro{#2}#5\EndMacro{#2}}%
            }%
        \fi
    }%
\fi

\newcommand*{\MacroB}[1]{b#1b}%
\newcommand*{\MacroA}[1]{a\MacroB{#1}a}%

\begin{document}
\MacroA{XXX}

\MacroB{YYY}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand what does `\ifnum#3=1…` do. After checking the number of parameters is 1, you call `\OldNewCommand{#2}{…}` with 0 arguments.

Comment: If you delete everything between `\ifnum` and `\else` and also the corresponding `\fi` (i.e., leaving only the `\IfBooleanTF`… it compiles fine here.

Comment: Does reading `#5` with `v` instead of `m` help? (I can't try it myself for I am on my phone)

Comment: For an `o` argument, the test is not `\IfBooleanTF`, but `\IfNoValueTF` or `\IfValueTF`. Of course, `\LetLtxMacro` is not needed for `\newcommand`, that has no argument.

Comment: Related Question: [Can I find out if I am in an environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319361/can-i-find-out-if-i-am-in-an-environment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are strange conditionals in your code. Moreover, `\IfBooleanTF` is for arguments of type `s` or `t`, not for `o`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newif\ifEnableTrace
\newcounter{NestingDepth}
\let\latexnewcommand\newcommand

\newcommand{\StartMacro}[1]{%
  \ifEnableTrace
    \typeout{**** DEBUG: (Depth=\arabic{NestingDepth}) Started macro `\string#1'.}%
    \stepcounter{NestingDepth}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\EndMacro}[1]{%
  \ifEnableTrace
    \addtocounter{NestingDepth}{-1}%
    \typeout{**** DEBUG: (Depth=\arabic{NestingDepth}) Completed macro `\string#1'.}%
  \fi
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewCommand}{smO{0}om}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#4}{\latexnewcommand*{#2}[#3]}{\latexnewcommand*{#2}[#3][#4]}}%
    {\IfNoValueTF{#4}{\latexnewcommand{#2}[#3]}{\latexnewcommand{#2}[#3][#4]}}%
  {\StartMacro{#2}#5\EndMacro{#2}}%
}

% if you want to enable tracing
\let\newcommand\NewCommand

\newcommand*{\MacroB}[1]{b#1b}
\newcommand*{\MacroA}[1]{a\MacroB{#1}a}

\begin{document}

\MacroA{XXX}

\MacroB{YYY}

\EnableTracetrue

\MacroA{XXX}

\MacroB{YYY}

\end{document}
```

Here's the terminal output

```
**** DEBUG: (Depth=0) Started macro `\MacroA'.
**** DEBUG: (Depth=1) Started macro `\MacroB'.
**** DEBUG: (Depth=1) Completed macro `\MacroB'.
**** DEBUG: (Depth=0) Completed macro `\MacroA'.
**** DEBUG: (Depth=0) Started macro `\MacroB'.
**** DEBUG: (Depth=0) Completed macro `\MacroB'.
```

Comment: As always, your solution works great. Two questions: 1. Why is `\LetLtxMacro` not needed here -- `\newcommand` has an optional parameter.  2. Why the `\ifEnableTrace` in `\StartMacro` and `\EndMacro`? Seems that it should just be around the `\let\newcommand\NewCommand`.

Comment: @PeterGrill (2) at least that's an extra since you can disable tracing at some point in the document, and reenable it again whenever you want.

Comment: @PeterGrill The first level expansion of `\newcommand` is `\@star@or@long\new@command`; no arguments. I added two levels for `EnableTrace`: you can enable tracing globally and then disable/enable it locally.

Answer (score 2):

You use

```
\ifnum#3=1\relax
  \OldNewcommand{#2}{\StartMacro{#2}#5\EndMacro{#2}}%
\else
```

which… after checking you pass `\newcommand\…[1]` gives you something like `\newcommand\…[0]`.

```
\ifnum#3=1\relax
  \OldNewcommand{#2}[1]{\StartMacro{#2}#5\EndMacro{#2}}%
\else
```

works.

By the way… why is it necessary the `\ifnum` at all? Just leaving the “else” branch of that `\ifnum` is enough:

```
%\def\EnableTrace{}
\documentclass{article}

%% All packages included here...
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}


%% Start of custom macros...
\ifdefined\EnableTrace
    \newcounter{NestingDepth}
    \newcommand*{\StartMacro}[1]{%
        \typeout{**** DEBUG: (Depth=\arabic{NestingDepth}) Started macro "\string#1".}%
        \stepcounter{NestingDepth}%
    }%
    \newcommand*{\EndMacro}[1]{%
        \addtocounter{NestingDepth}{-1}%
        \typeout{**** DEBUG: (Depth=\arabic{NestingDepth}) Completed macro "\string#1".}%
    }%
    % --------------
    \LetLtxMacro{\OldNewcommand}{\newcommand}%
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\newcommand}{%
        s%    #1 = * (ignored for now to keep the code below simple)
        m%    #2 = macro name
        O{1}% #3 = number of paramaters
        o%    #4 = default value for first optional parameter (if there is one)
        m%    #5 = code to execute
    }{%
        %
%       \ifnum#3=1\relax
%           \OldNewcommand{#2}{\StartMacro{#2}#5\EndMacro{#2}}%
%       \else
            \IfBooleanTF{#4}{%
                % first parameter of macro being defined is optional, as default value is provided
                \OldNewcommand{#2}[#3][#4]{\StartMacro{#2}#5\EndMacro{#2}}%
            }{%
                % first parameter of macro being defined is mandatory
                \OldNewcommand{#2}[#3]{\StartMacro{#2}#5\EndMacro{#2}}%
            }%
%       \fi
    }%
\fi

\newcommand*{\MacroB}[1]{b#1b}%
\newcommand*{\MacroA}[1]{a\MacroB{#1}a}%

\begin{document}
\MacroA{XXX}

\MacroB{YYY}
\end{document}
```

---

By the way, why not default the number of arguments to `[0]` so it works exactly as the original `\newcommand`?

Comment: Hmmm... You are right, it should have been `\ifnum#3=0` and the the default should be '0'. Those two changes fix this MWE.  SO, then I need both the `ifnum#3=0` and `else` branches.

Comment: The `\IfBooleanTF` (which as noted by egreg should be `\IfValueTF`) is enough (after defaulting to `[0]` parameters). `\newcommand\foo[0]{…}` is the same as `\newcommand\foo{…}`.