# Determine File Name and Line Number Where a Macro is Invoked From

Tags: macros, package-writing, debugging, jobname

Wondering if there is any way to print out (for debugging purposes) the file name and the line number from where a macro is *invoked* (not where it is defined).  My attempt to use [the `currfile` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/currfile) only shows the main file name in the output:

```
**** ------ Enabling macro trace
**** DEBUG: (Depth=0) (File=TeX-SE.tex, Line=0) Started macro `\MacroA'.
**** DEBUG: (Depth=1) (File=TeX-SE.tex, Line=0) Started macro `\MacroB'.
**** DEBUG: (Depth=2) (File=TeX-SE.tex, Line=0) Started macro `\MacroC'.
**** DEBUG: (Depth=2) (File=TeX-SE.tex, Line=0) Completed macro `\MacroC'.
**** DEBUG: (Depth=1) (File=TeX-SE.tex, Line=0) Completed macro `\MacroB'.
**** DEBUG: (Depth=0) (File=TeX-SE.tex, Line=0) Completed macro `\MacroA'.
**** ------ Disabling macro trace
```

The desired output is something like:

```
**** ------ Enabling macro trace
**** DEBUG: (Depth=0) (File=TeX-SE.tex, Line=59) Started macro `\MacroA'.
**** DEBUG: (Depth=1) (File=MyMacros.sty, Line=7) Started macro `\MacroB'.
**** DEBUG: (Depth=2) (File=MyMacros.sty, Line=3) Started macro `\MacroC'.
**** DEBUG: (Depth=2) (File=MyMacros.sty, Line=3) Completed macro `\MacroC'.
**** DEBUG: (Depth=1) (File=MyMacros.sty, Line=7) Completed macro `\MacroB'.
**** DEBUG: (Depth=0) (File=TeX-SE.tex, Line=59) Completed macro `\MacroA'.
**** ------ Disabling macro trace
```

### Notes:

- This is a follow-up to [Redefine \newcommand to insert code at start and end of custom macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195016/redefine-newcommand-to-insert-code-at-start-and-end-of-custom-macros).
- I am only interested in doing this for my custom macros, not those that are part of other packages.

### Code:

```
%\RequirePackage{filecontents}% <--- Commented out to prevent overwriting an existing file.
\begin{filecontents*}{MyMacros.sty}
    \newcommand*{\MacroC}[1]{cc#1cc}
    \newcommand*{\MacroB}[1]{\MacroC{CC}b#1b}
    \newcommand*{\MacroA}[1]{a\MacroB{#1}a}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{currfile}

%\usepackage{letltxmacro}
%\LetLtxMacro{\OldUsepackage}{\usepackage}
%\renewcommand{\usepackage}[2][]{\edef\currfilename{#2}\OldUsepackage[#1]{#2}}%


\newcommand*{\CurrentLineNumber}{0}%

\newif\ifEnableTrace
\newcounter{NestingDepth}
\let\latexnewcommand\newcommand


\newcommand{\StartMacro}[1]{%
  \ifEnableTrace
    \typeout{**** DEBUG: (Depth=\arabic{NestingDepth}) (File=\currfilename, Line=\CurrentLineNumber) Started macro `\string#1'.}%
    \stepcounter{NestingDepth}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\EndMacro}[1]{%
  \ifEnableTrace
    \addtocounter{NestingDepth}{-1}%
    \typeout{**** DEBUG: (Depth=\arabic{NestingDepth}) (File=\currfilename, Line=\CurrentLineNumber) Completed macro `\string#1'.}%
  \fi
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewCommand}{smO{0}om}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#4}{\latexnewcommand*{#2}[#3]}{\latexnewcommand*{#2}[#3][#4]}}%
    {\IfNoValueTF{#4}{\latexnewcommand{#2}[#3]}{\latexnewcommand{#2}[#3][#4]}}%
  {\StartMacro{#2}#5\EndMacro{#2}}%
}

% if you want to enable tracing
\let\newcommand\NewCommand

\usepackage{MyMacros}

\begin{document}

\MacroA{XXX}
\MacroB{YYY}

\EnableTracetrue
\typeout{**** ------ Enabling macro trace}
\MacroA{XXX}

\typeout{**** ------ Disabling macro trace}
\EnableTracefalse
\MacroB{YYY}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\the\inputlineno`

Comment: @egreg: That's definitely a good start -- seems to get the line number where the `\MacroA` is invoked, not where `\MacroB` is invoked, at least with my naive usage of it: `Line=\the\inputlineno`.

Comment: If `\MacroA` invokes `\MacroB`, then `\MacroB` will show the same line number as `\MacroA`, in that call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the answer here (such as it is) is 'no'. TeX's macro expansion means that when `\macroA` is read it is replaced by the definition, which is then 'there'. Where that definition comes from, what it is, *etc.* is unimportant. So from TeX's point of view `\macroA => \macroB` means that `\macroB` is 'here' whether it's defined here or not. At the same time, you have to bear in mind that any clever re-definitions to help trace material have to keep expandable macros expandable, and that means no assignments, writing to the log, *etc.*, which limits what can be achieved.